# What does this mean? void* free_me = 0;

Tags: ios, void

```
uint8_t* baseAddress = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(imageBuffer); 
    void* free_me = 0;
    if (true) { // iOS bug?
        uint8_t* tmp = baseAddress;
        int bytes = bytesPerRow*height;
        free_me = baseAddress = (uint8_t*)malloc(bytes);
        baseAddress[0] = 0xdb;
        memcpy(baseAddress,tmp,bytes);
    }
```

This program is found in zxing package, what does this sentence "void* free_me = 0;" mean? What does this program do? Any tips will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`void* free_me = 0` declares a "generic" pointer `free_me` and gives  it the value `0`

Generic pointers may be used, pretty much as any other pointer (`int*`,`char*`,etc), with the exception that pointers to void can actually point  to ANY data type.

Answer (score 2):

This code is very obscure and is there, as the comment says, to workaround an obscure bug in iOS. In early versions of the AV Foundation Framework on certain devices, very strange things happened with the buffering. This code copies the buffer rather than using it directly. The `if (true)` stuff is there so that we can (eventually) disable this path for devices/SDKs that don't need the workaround.

Comment: why is the first byte overwritten by 0xdb?

Comment: I must have stuck that in there while debugging, trying to figure out what was going on. 0xdb is my 8-bit debugging value, shorthand for 0xdeadbeef, my 32-bit debugging value. It's supposed to be blitzed by the following memcpy but in some incarnation of the code (before the memcpy, I presume) I wasn't sure the copy was happening correctly so I wrote 0xdb in there and checked that it wasn't 0xdb afterwards. Hopefully I'll get a chance to clean this up before long ...